# Angular(5) - lazy loading and canActivate guard - StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router

So, we have quite a big app and we started working on optimizations.... one of the optimizations were lazy loading some parts....

so we have Demo pages with whole load of example usage that we DON'T want anywhere but on out DEV environment...

so lazy loading that part was quite easy...

in our app-routing module we have

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {path: 'design', canActivate: ['DevOnlyGuard'], loadChildren: 'app/pages/demo/demo.module#DemoPagesModule'},
    ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

So without canActivate route all works fine and demo routes are loaded lazily...

now, if I add this canActivate in my guard, that looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DevOnlyGuard implements  CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return (environment.envName === 'dev');
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error once I hit the demo route:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError[DevOnlyGuard]:
>   StaticInjectorError[DevOnlyGuard]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for DevOnlyGuard! Error: StaticInjectorError[DevOnlyGuard]:  ....

even if I added the Guard to the list of providers in my app.module
like

```
providers: [
    ...
    DevOnlyGuard,
];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad instead of CanActivate?

Comment: @stojevskimilan, yeah.... tried that... the same result :/

Comment: have you tried removing single quotes from `canActivate: ['DevOnlyGuard']`

Comment: @haifzhan cannot believe this worked! I tried a lot of stuff.... and examples are everywhere with the quotes... omg :/  THANKS

Comment: @DS_web_developer glad it helps!

Comment: @haifzhan hahha nice :)

Comment: DS and @stojevskimilan  post example. this may help people who encounter the same issue:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove single quotes from `canActivate: ['DevOnlyGuard']`

Below is how should we use canActivate:

Method 1:

```
  @Injectable()
    class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}

      canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
        return this.permissions.canActivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
      }
    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          {
            path: 'team/:id',
            component: TeamCmp,
            canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
          }
        ])
      ],
      providers: [CanActivateTeam, UserToken, Permissions]
    })
    class AppModule {}
```

Method 2(with Single Quote...):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        canActivate: ['canActivateTeam']
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'canActivateTeam',
      useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => true
    }
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```